# Komma oder kein Komma?

Tags: comma

> Das ist ja wie in Indien, nur, dass die wenigstens 50 Cent pro Stunde verdienen.

*"Nur"* ist in diesem Fall ein Partikel, *"Das ist ja wie in Indien."* ein "Hauptsatz" und *",dass die wenigstens 50 Cent pro Stunde verdienen"* ein "Nebensatz".

Ist mein Gedankengang so richtig und die Kommas richtig gesetzt?

Comment: Duden hat dein Beispiel, mit anderer Zeichensetzung und ohne weitere Erklärung: *man erfuhr nichts, nur dass er überraschend abgereist sei*. Es ist also davon auszugehen, dass das zweite Komma vor dem "dass" falsch ist.

Comment: @tofro Ich weiß, wir sind da unterschiedlicher Ansicht. Was den Duden und sprachliche Autorität angeht, fällt mir immer das Heinz-Erhard-Zitat ein: Was weißt du'dn?

Comment: "Nur" ist hier übrigens mMn keine Partikel, das ist es nur in Konstruktionen wie "Wo bleibt er nur?" oder "Nur keine Panik!".

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Ich würde kein Komma setzen, weil das *nur* bei sinnvoller Betrachtung (entgegen der Charakterisierung in der Frage) selbst zum Konnektor gehört. Das ist vielleicht nicht hundertprozentig eindeutig (siehe weiter unten), aber syntaktisch naheliegend und wird in der Literatur auch so nachvollzogen (namentlich von Breindl et al, HdK II/1, 2014, 18, 43: *nur dass* als eigenständiger Postponierer und "phraseologischer Konnektor"; ebenso Buscha, *Lexikon deutscher Konjunktionen*, 1989, 88: *nur daß* als "subordinierende zusammengesetzte Konjunktion").

Wenn man diese Prämisse akzeptiert, wird es m.E. schwer, ein Komma zu rechtfertigen, denn das stünde ja dann *zwischen* den Komponenten *eines* komplexen Konnektors. Wie man das begründen will, erschließt sich mir mit Blick auf etablierte Kommaregeln nicht. In den Beispielen der beiden angeführten Werke wird *nur dass* entsprechend, soweit ersichtlich, auch stets ohne dazwischenstehendes Komma verwendet.

Apropos Regeln, zu der Frage etwas in den amtlichen Rechtschreibregeln zu finden, ist eher schwierig. Am relevantesten erscheint § 74 E1(2):

> § 74. Nebensätze grenzt man mit Komma ab; sind sie eingeschoben, so
> schließt man sie mit paarigem Komma ein. [...]
>
> E1: Besteht die Einleitung eines Nebensatzes aus einem Einleitewort
> und weiteren Wörtern, so gilt:
>
> (1) Man setzt das Komma vor die ganze Wortgruppe: [...]
>
> (2) In einigen Fällen kann der Schreibende zusätzlich ein Komma
> zwischen den Bestandteilen der Wortgruppe setzen: *Morgen wird es
> regnen, angenommen(,) dass der Wetterbericht stimmt. Wir fahren
> morgen, ausgenommen(,) wenn es regnet. Ich glaube nicht, dass er
> anruft, geschweige(,) dass er vorbeikommt. Ich glaube nicht, dass er
> anruft, geschweige denn(,) dass er vorbeikommt. Ich komme morgen,
> gleichviel(,) ob er es will oder nicht. Ich werde ihnen gegenüber
> abweisend oder entgegenkommend sein, je nachdem(,) ob sie hartnäckig
> oder sachlich sind. Egal(,) welche Farbe sie sich aussucht, sie wird
> immer gut aussehen.*

Allein, wodurch sich diese "einigen Fälle", in denen das zulässig ist, nun von den anderen abgrenzen, bleibt dunkel. Eine klare Antwort auf die Frage findet sich hier mithin nicht.

Abweichend vom Obenstehenden schreiben, leider nicht weiter begründet, Métrich/Faucher in ihrem Wörterbuch deutscher Partikeln, 2009, 669 (nachdem sie *nur* als Konnektor einführen, der u.a. einen aus einem *dass*-Satz bestehenden Nachtrag einleiten kann): "[Z]wischen nur und dass steht oft ein Komma, das aber auch fehlen kann[.]" Ob das jetzt bloß ein empirischer Befund oder eine eigene Regelauslegung ist, ist nicht ganz klar. Ich wollte es hier nur der Vollständigkeit halber ergänzen. Als Korpusbelege werden dort zum Beispiel angeführt: *Graue Strähnen drin, eine ganze Menge sogar, nur, daß er so genau noch nie hingeschaut hatte. Auch er nimmt die Beschäftigung seiner Knabenjahre auf. Nur, daß er niemals Steine gesammelt und Briefmarken eingeklebt hat, sondern den kleinen Mädchen nachgeschlichen ist, lüstern und stumm.*

Unter sprachstrukturierenden Gesichtspunkten halte ich das Komma persönlich - selbst wenn es fakultativ gesetzt werden könnte -, ohnedies für störend. Das wird auch deutlich, wenn man den hiesigen Fall mit Adverbkonnektor-*nur* im (Vor-)Vorfeld vergleicht. Also etwa: *Ich mag Autos, nur, bei meinem Einkommen kann ich mir keines leisten.* Das ist ein sinnvolles und auch rhythmisch "wegweisendes" Komma; in der Tat kann man nach *nur* auch gut Luft holen/eine Pause setzen. Im Beispielsatz hier stört das kommaseparierte *nur* hingegen den Lesefluss, da es im Allgemein ganz nah am *dass* gesprochen wird.

Comment: Ich bewundere wirklich die akribische Aueinandersetzung mit einem so nichtigen Problem! (Ich meine das ganz ehrlich und ohne jede Ironie!) Als ich die Frage las, dachte ich: ist doch völlig Schnurz! Beide Ansichten - dafür und dagegen - haben etwas für sich. So ein Komma hat ja eine bedeutungstragende Funktion, die ich in diesem Satz nicht erkennen kann. D.h. ich kann keinen Unterschied erkennen. Und dann wäre es mir viel zu mühsam, dafür irgend welche Regeln ausfindig zu machen. Dennoch: legitime Frage, excellente Antwort. Hut ab und +1.